# Design View of a DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, gui-designer

Is there a way to preview GUI in a DataTemplate? e.g. if I have a Resource Dictionary, containing a DataTemplate, and the Data template contains GUI code, like

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="AAA"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Can I view just the stackpanel? (like previewing a UserControl in design view). If not possible with original VS, is there a plugin for that?

Comment: Expression Blend can do it. But i´m not aware of any tool for visual studio that visualizes the DataTemplate

Comment: Unless you want to copy the StackPanel into a blank UserControl and use the VS design view editor, edit and the copy back to the DataTemplate, you should use Expression Blend as @Jehof said. I did this myself in some occations when I didn't feel like using Blend.

Comment: That would have been a nice feature for Visual Studio 2013, for people like me that don't like to use Expression Blend. Another way would be to create a separate XAML file containing the DataTemplate (you don't have to create a UserControl) and then link your XAML file in your ResourceDictionary.

Comment: @TheodoreZographos how to do this in particular. This is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 20):

Visual Studio doesn't support doing this, but Expression Blend does, if you can get access to it. Here's some instructions on several ways to edit template resources:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908(v=expression.40).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

In particular, if you'd like to edit a DataTemplate located in a ResourceDictionary you would:

- Load the project in Blend
- Locate the .xaml file containing the ResourceDictionary in the **Resources** panel (docked right by default)
- Locate the DataTemplate in the list of resources (by Key)
- Click **Edit Resource**

I know this an old question but I hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't work for projects targeting Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, and possibly earlier versions

Answer (score 1):

If you reference your template down in the body of your control, such as `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"`, you can place your cursor on the name of the template and press F12 to have Visual Studio render the template in the XAML designer.

For some reason, *this only works once*. You have to close and reopen the form to see another template rendered. Surely there's some way to avoid this but I haven't been able to figure it out.