# How to preview an ItemTemplate in the XAML designer

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml

Say I have a simple ItemTemplate for a ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListItems}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TextItem">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Item}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

<sup>`MainPage.xaml`</sup>

When I run the app, I get a ListView populated with TextBlocks - one for each item in `ListItems` (which is a behind defined variable). However, in the XAML designer, I see nothing.

So, is there a way to preview the ItemTemplate/DataTemplate in the XAML designer, with a set number of placeholder TextBlocks with placeholder text replacing the `Text="{x:Bind Item}"`? Or just preview a single TextBlock?

---

This is not a duplicate of

- [Design View of a DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922523/design-view-of-a-datatemplate-in-a-resourcedictionary-in-visual-studio) - because I can't use Blend. Everything I've looked up that says use Blend in a certain way merely gives me the message 'This feature is not available for projects targeting "Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)"'
- [Can I preview my DataTemplate(s) in my collection-based controls in the designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987860/can-i-preview-my-datatemplates-in-my-collection-based-controls-in-the-designer) - well, perhaps it is, but I don't understand the accepted answer, which is now several years old. An answer containing an example tailored to my question would be really helpful.

Comment: If it's needed, I can add the behind code in a little while

Comment: It seems you are looking for a solution for design time data in UWP... there should be several links available on MSDN, maybe check those out? Like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/displaying-data-in-the-designer BUT there does seem to be a problem with FCU https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/172286/design-time-data-in-uwp-library-not-working-in-vs.html

Comment: @Depechie I have read that docs page, but it says "if you're using `{x:Bind}` then your bindings at least show placeholder values on the design surface". Perhaps this is to do with the apparent bug that prevents use of Blend? If so, I can only wait until they patch it

Comment: Can use Blend? It can see it.

Comment: @lindexi No I can't use Blend, as all instructions for using it result in me seeing the message 'This feature is not available for projects targeting "Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)"', which might be because of a bug, as Depechie has suggested

Comment: Have you implemented DataContext in your xaml?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I thought you can't use DataContext with x:Bind? (Btw, I was missing an x:DataType - now added)

Comment: I used `Binding` in `DataTemplate`. The xaml designer worked.

Comment: I'm having this issue too. I want to use `x:Bind` since its compile time checked but I can't see any data in the designer and there seems to be no way to set it.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft actually posted a (semi helpful) tutorial on this in April of this year: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-designtime-data?view=vs-2019)

#### Requirements

Whatever you want to display, you will need this at the top of your XAML code (should be there by default if you created the page using VS's templates):

```xml
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

#### A simple list of strings

For something simple like a list of strings, something like this will work just fine (taken from the above mentioned MSDN page):

```xml
<ListView>
    <d:ListView.Items>
        <system:String>Item One</system:String>
        <system:String>Item Two</system:String>
        <system:String>Item Three</system:String>
    </d:ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

#### Display something more complex

If you want to use a data source from somewhere else in your code, it gets a little more ugly:

First you need to set your data context (usually done at the page level, but you can also add it just on the element where you want to use it):

```xml
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance
                  yournamespace:YourDataSourceClass,
                  IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

And on the ListView add:

```xml
d:ItemsSource="{Binding data}"
```

If you are using an ItemTemplate, you will need to add "d:" variants for everything you want to pull from your data source.

#### Full example code:

XAML:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="exampleApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:exampleApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:DesignTimeData,
                                     IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListItems}" d:ItemsSource="{Binding DummyData}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TextItem">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Item}" d:Text="{Binding Item}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

C#:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace exampleApp {
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
        public ObservableCollection<TextItem> ListItems;
        public MainPage() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //populate you ListItems list
        }
    }
    public class TextItem {
        public string Item { get; set; }
    }
    public class DesignTimeData {
        public ObservableCollection<TextItem> DummyData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TextItem> {
        new TextItem { Item = "foo" },
        new TextItem { Item = "bar" },
        new TextItem { Item = "bla" },
        new TextItem { Item = "blubb" }
        };
    }
}
```

#### Remarks

- It seems you have to use "Binding" rather than "x:Bind" for the design-time bindings. From what I understand, x:Bind works using code generated at compile time, which is not executed by the XAML designer
- When you change your Binding declarations or data source code, you will have to recompile to see the changes in the designer. Other design changes will reflect in real time
- Binding is more limited than x:Bind in some regards (notably you cannot bind to class methods using Binding, only x:Bind). Keep that in mind when writing your design-time data
- Sadly some of the more convenient ways of getting design-time data into your app are WPF and Xamarin only (Blends' data window, data declared in XAML file, and especially [auto-generated sample data)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-design-time-sample-data?view=vs-2019)

(Everything was tested using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.10.3.)