# Visual Studio 2022 doesnt show DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF window with a DataTemplate with a TabControl.

If I have the TabControl in the DataTemplate, I don't get a preview of the control in the Visual Studio pre-view.  If I copy the section contained in the Border control stright into the windows StackPanel I can see it.

Is there something wrong with how I've set it up or is this a limitation of a DataTemplate?

Here's a version with just the template

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp_PS.WindowTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp_PS"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WindowTest" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SelectedItemToItemsSource x:Key="SelectedItemToItemsSource" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserGrid" >
        <Border Background="Chocolate" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TabControl Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="684" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                    <TabItem Header="Mailbox Properties">
                        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Content="Mailbox Type" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,60,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Label Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,90,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  Margin="20,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button  Content="Save" Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Width="131" Height="34" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl BindingGroup="{Binding UpdateBindingGroup, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserGrid}" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMailbox, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemToItemsSource}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

That shows
[image]

Heres the same code but the section in the border control copied out to the main stack panel

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp_PS.WindowTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp_PS"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WindowTest" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SelectedItemToItemsSource x:Key="SelectedItemToItemsSource" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserGrid" >
        <Border Background="Chocolate" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TabControl Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="684" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                    <TabItem Header="Mailbox Properties">
                        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Content="Mailbox Type" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,60,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Label Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,90,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  Margin="20,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button  Content="Save" Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Width="131" Height="34" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl BindingGroup="{Binding UpdateBindingGroup, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserGrid}" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMailbox, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemToItemsSource}}" />
    <Border Background="Chocolate" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TabControl Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="684" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <TabItem Header="Mailbox Properties">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="Mailbox Type" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,60,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Label Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,90,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  Margin="20,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button  Content="Save" Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Width="131" Height="34" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>


</StackPanel>
```

This shows [image]

I can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922523/design-view-of-a-datatemplate-in-a-resourcedictionary-in-visual-studio) but its 10 years old so not sure if its still relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: You may have a refresh issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974939/difficulty-with-tabcontrol-tabitem-refresh

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm having the issue in VS, it works fine when I run it.  I think the URL is about when the OP is running code.

Comment: User is getting an empty response.  The DataContext.SaveCommand is empty.  You need to get the response status when user is running code.  Most likely there is a credential issue when user makes a request to the server.

Comment: HI @jdweng . This is in the XAML editor in Visual Studio, not when its being run. It actually shows fine when its run, I just cant see the form in the designer.  I've also cleared out a lot of code to concentrate on the issue I am having.

Comment: It depends on how you added to object.  The designer only show controls that were added in the designer and not the ones added while running.  You can open the designer.cs file to see which controls were added in the designer.

Comment: I'm not even running it.  This is jsut in VS design, not debug.  I've put copies of the code up which can just be loaded in a test project in VS to see what happens if they have the time.  Thanks

Comment: The only object that appear in the designer are the ones in the designer.cs file.  Runtime object that are not in the designer.cs do not appear in the designer.

Comment: So its because the DataTemplate is declared under Window.Resources?  In that case how do you preview a DataTemplate to design the contents?

Comment: Only way is to design dynamically.  Run code and then make adjustments.  You could add some boxes during testing to help adjust the sizes.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to make using a dataTemplate a retrograde step but I guess it is what it is.  Thanks for the advice.